# Large number of Requests and Errors on GCE

Tags: google-compute-engine

I've been struggling with a GCE issue for a while and I would like to ask for some help. On the developer console I see large number of API requests that I don't know where originated from. I'm pretty sure that I'm not running any services / jobs that can burn the API quota. I see many errors as well. All my VM instances and other resources are working fine, but the issue concern me. I linked a few screens from the dev console about whats happening. I would really appreciate any help!

Thanks!

https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-7_HaZLZxvF0/VC14TMVCKoI/AAAAAAAAE6Q/0b8NvjxttMQ/s1600/01.png
https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-TdXJu2VQ7qA/VC14mcy2AOI/AAAAAAAAE6g/O8VPcoRJpfc/s1600/03.png

Answer (score 0):

IT seems like you're using the Google Compute Engine API. When using gcloud compute commands or the Google Compute Engine console tool, you're making requests to the API. Also check if you have an app that uses the service account to make requests to GCE. You can visit this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api-rate-limits) for more information

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Thats why the issue concern me, because I use the CLI tools once or twice a week at most and besides that I don't run / use scripts or anything else. Regarding the service accounts, I have Stackdriver attached to my account as a monitoring tool, but it shouldn't do more then 20.000 API request / day, that would be abnormal. In the past two days my API usage dropped drastically and I didn't do anything special, so maybe it was an issue on Google's side. Anyway, it seems the issue is solved.